# Datatables Column text continue to next column

Tags: datatables

As you can see on the screenshot my second column text is overriding the next column text. Is there a way to avoid this and adjust the value according to how long is the text in each column ?. I tried scrollX:true but it does not work. Thank you[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is not a DataTables specific problem. You can solve it with CSS [word-break](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-break) option.

Just create a CSS class like;

```
.breakAll {
    word-break: break-all;
}
```

and use DataTables [className](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.className) option to add this class to the target column and to break words in that column.

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
  "columnDefs": [
    { className: "my_class", "targets": [ 0 ] }
  ]
});
```

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle project? So I can help you directly.